# Flashing Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

There is some problem when I am trying to install Ubuntu Touch. The [Tutorial](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9300) tells me to flash the device file (Ubuntu-Touch-i9300_build3.zip) first and then the image file (wily-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz).

Well, I successfully flash the device file, but the image file just contains  a whole system, and android recovery wont recognize it. Am I doing something wrong? Please help. Thanks.